# Replace 2 Bootstrap columns with 2 hidden columns on click. Rails 4, Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.

I have column system that represent 4 similar advertisements at the bottom of page.

In view:

```
    <div class="row similar">
                    <% @recomended_ads.each do |advertisement| %>
                        <div class="col-md-3 block-3 clearfix">
                            <div class="block-3-image pull-left">
                               <%= link_to (image_tag advertisement.pictures.first.image,:title=> advertisement.name, :width=>210),advertisement %>        
                            </div><!-- End block-3-image -->

                        BASIC CONTENT!


                    </div><!-- End block-3 -->

                   <%end%>


           <div class="col-md-3 block-3 clearfix" style="height:220px !important;" id="vips">
                  NEW CONTENT
          </div
          <div class="col-md-3 block-3 clearfix" style="height:220px !important;" id="vips2">
                 NEW CONTENT 2
       </div>
    </div>
```

In controller:

```
@recomended_ads = Advertisement.where(:country_id=>@location.id).where("recomend >= ?", Time.now).where.not(id: @advertisement.id).limit(4).order("RAND()")
```

Basicaly it generates maximum 4 columns.

What I need:

I need to change last 2 column content when user clicks on specifick link.
So far I have created:

```
<div class="col-md-3 block-3 clearfix" style="height:220px !important;" id="vips">
   NEW CONTENT
</div
<div class="col-md-3 block-3 clearfix" style="height:220px !important;" id="vips2">
   NEW CONTENT 2
</div>
```

These two columns are hidden and are inside the same row as those I want to hide/replace.

I came up with script, that show/hide those hidden colums

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.question4').click(function(e){
         $('#vips').slideToggle("fast");
          $('#vips2').slideToggle("fast");

     e.preventDefault();

})
});//end of read
```

Works perfect if there is just TWO default columns `.limit(2)` in controller action.
If there is at more than 2 those colums are pushed down to next row. And that is what I don't want.

Question:

1) Is there possible to change that limit value from 4 to 2 if click on link has made? Without page reload? I believe Jquery can't change anything on server side.

2) Or there are other trick to achieve something like this ?

**At this point my code does this.**
[image]

And bullets show how It should look like.

Any advise would be great?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with solution.

It is messy but does what I need.

1) In view I changed this line `<% @recomended_ads.each do |advertisement| %>` to: `<% @recomended_ads.to_enum.with_index(1) do |advertisement, index| %>` So I can set index for each column.

2) Then changed `<div class="col-md-3 block-3 clearfix">` to    <`div class="col-md-3 block-3 clearfix" id=<%= "recomended_#{index}" %> >`  So I can create diferent div id for each column.

3) Then script looks like this now.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.question4').click(function(e){
       $('#recomended_3').slideToggle("fast");
                $('#recomended_4').slideToggle("fast");
                $('#recomended_5').slideToggle("fast");
             $('#vips').slideToggle("fast");
              $('#vips2').slideToggle("fast");     
         e.preventDefault();
    })
});//end of ready
```

And this works like charm. 
Just transition effect is ugly, I will go for other solution.

I hope somebody it will help.